# VSCode Version 1.60.0 Changed Interactive View to Epilepsy -- Old or Web view available?

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-interactive

Is there a way to revert back to the older versions Interactive View, or any Interactive view options I should be aware of?   I work with python in interactive notebooks and the recent update in the last couple days to 1.60.0 has changed my 'interactive' window completely.  The current setting is almost unusable, as running a '.py' results in the screen flickering (epileptic inducing style) as the script runs.  Previously, I remember having to set an option for 'web viewing' or similar in order to get a smooth running experience as scripts run.  Not finding anything in the newest version.
Any help would be appreciated.  I'm mostly using pandas & numpy with periodic print statements to notify me as things run.  I use a lot of table/Dataframe viewing, so the new 1.60.0 tables do seem a bit better than the web view I had previously.